# How to write data from JSON file to excel file by openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a `json` file with data that I would like to save to an `xlsx` file. I used the `openpyxl` library and stopped at the stage of creating a `for` loop to save each user in turn in a separate line and his data in separate cells.

json file:

```
{
"entries": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "cn": "Bruce Wayne",
            "displayName": "Batman",
            "distinguishedName": "CN=Bruce Wayne,OU=Users,OU=DC-COMICS,DC=universum,DC=local",
            "primaryGroupID": 513,
            "sAMAccountName": "batman",
            "sAMAccountType": 805306368,
            "userAccountControl": 514,
            "whenCreated": "2016-04-19 10:06:25+00:00"
        },
        "dn": "CN=Bruce Wayne,OU=Users,OU=DC-COMICS,DC=universum,DC=local"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "cn": "Clark Kent",
            "displayName": "Superman",
            "distinguishedName": "CN=Clark Kent,OU=Users,OU=DC-COMICS,DC=universum,DC=local",
            "primaryGroupID": 513,
            "sAMAccountName": "superman",
            "sAMAccountType": 805306368,
            "userAccountControl": 514,
            "whenCreated": "2016-04-19 10:06:25+00:00"
        },
        "dn": "CN=Clark Kent,OU=Users,OU=DC-COMICS,DC=universum,DC=local"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code:

```
import json
import configparser

### load main_config.ini file
main_config_file = './config/main_config.ini' # sciezka do pliku main_config.ini z 
ustawieniami
main_config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
main_config.read(main_config_file)

### VARIABLES
# from configs files
root_path = main_config['GLOBAL']['root_path']
json_dir = main_config['GLOBAL']['json_dir']
encoded_retrived_users_file = main_config['USERS']['encoded_users_file_name']

# load data from JSON file
encoded_retrived_users = './JSON/test.json'
#encoded_retrived_users = root_path + json_dir + encoded_retrived_users_file # sciezka 
do pliku encoded_users_from_LDAP.json
with open(encoded_retrived_users, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    retrived_users = data['entries']

### CONSOLE VIEW
print("----------------------------------")

for user in retrived_users:
    no = str(i)
    attributes = user['attributes']
    cn = attributes['cn']
    sAMAccountName = attributes['sAMAccountName']
    i += i

    print("No:  " + no)
    print("cn:              " + cn)
    print("sAMAccountName:  " + sAMAccountName)
    print("----------------------------------")

### EXCEL
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

# Grab the active worksheet
ws_01 = wb.active

# Set the title of the worksheet
ws_01.title = "llogon>30d"

# Set first row
ws_01.cell(1, 1, "cn")
ws_01.cell(1, 2, "sAMA")

# Save it in an Excel file
wb.save("./test/test.xlsx")
```

What I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: Would using pandas be an option?

Comment: There's no code that writes to Excel in the question. By the time `import openpyxl` is called, `retrived_users` is an array of objects, not JSON. Have you tried looping over `retrived_users` and writing the attributes you want to Excel? Eg `ws_01.cell(iRow, 1, attributes["cn"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `import openpyxl` is called, `retrived_users` is an array of objects, not JSON. The same code that writes to the console can be used to write to an Excel file :

```
wb = Workbook()
ws_01 = wb.active
ws_01.title = "llogon>30d"

i=0
for user in retrived_users:
    no = str(i)
    attributes = user['attributes']
    cn = attributes['cn']
    sAMAccountName = attributes['sAMAccountName']

    ws_01.cell(i, 1, cn)
    ws_01.cell(i, 2, sAMAccountName)
    i += i
wb.save("./test/test.xlsx")
```

It's certainly possible to write more elegant code, but this should work

Answer (score 1):

An option using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```python
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    k:[i['attributes'][k] for i in j['entries']]
    for k in j['entries'][0]['attributes'].keys()
})
df.whenCreated = pd.to_datetime(df.whenCreated).dt.tz_localize(None)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

###### Output:

[image: Screenshot of a created excel sheet]